# phpMyAdmin says: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] ... not OK

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin and it works fine. At the bottom of the pages however, there is this error message:

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

In that page, the only red row is this:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
>   User preferences: Disabled

In the configuration I have this:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';

The pma_userconfig was missing from my phpmyadmin db so I found the create_tables.sql from my phpMyAdmin installation and I ran that, then restarted apache and mysql. The table has been created, but the error is not gone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a reboot it is now working.

So the trick was to manually execute create_tables.sql, you can just copy everything into the phpMyAdmin sql window and execute it. This created the missing tables.

Comment: how to manually run create_tables.sql,

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N access phpmyadmin, click on the SQL tab (without selecting any database) and paste the file contents there. Otherwise, start mysql from command line and feed it the file. The file can be found in the PhpMyAdmin folder, depending on your installation. In Ubuntu it was /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/create_tables.sql.gz (need to uncompress to use)

Comment: mysql -u root -p < create_tables.sql is this right???